# JQuery click event on select element click does not work in chrome on Linux (chrome on Windows works)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

When I click on the select element in chrome, the event does not get triggered on first click (but after that, i.e. on second, third...). Why and how can I change that? (works in FF and in Chrome on Windows)

```js
 $("select").click(function() {
   console.log("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>a</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pv2eajux/

---

Note: click on the text, not on the arrow

Answer (score 0):

I have finally fixed it by replacing `click` with `mouseup`

```js
 $("select").mouseup(function() {
   console.log("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>a</option>
</select>
```